# Browser: Network - response time shows 2 seconds when it displays after ~15

Tags: performance, browser, response

I wanted to check how quickly my web application will display results for a query : SELECT * FROM orders.

the query returns about 20k records on one page and it takes about 15 seconds

Why on every browser the response time stops after two seconds? Is it because the browser has trouble displaying so many records per one page? at 70k it gets out of memory.

Database - mysql on hosting

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNIAN.jpg)

correct response time

Comment: Please post TEXT results from LAST 200 lines of your Error Log after this event has been reported for analysis and you have completed FLUSH LOGS; from your MySQL Command Prompt..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check how long it takes for the web app to process. You can add logging before and after doing the query.
You also could add some logging of the current time, when receiving the request and before returning the response.

As for why the request stops after two seconds, I don't think we have enough information to decide.
It could be from the web server default configuration that you use.

In my opinion, displaying 20k records might not be an efficient approach.
Other than the time to query and response time.
You might want to consider the looping that happens on the front end.

Personally, I would recommend paging at a lower number, and if you need to display all the data at once. You might consider using lazy loading as an option.

I know this is a very generic answer, but hopefully, this could help you out.